# Nodejs Restful web services perfomance application

Tags: node.js, performance

I'm using nodejs to create a web services, mongodb database. I have a api return response for client ~ 1 million records (documentations in mongodb). Angularjs client have to wait (pending) response from server. My response is dynamically ( 500 thoundsand, 1 million, 1.2 mi... change with date) so I can't cache result or just cache temp into storage browse. I'm researching anyway can create my application more performance. I'm reading the way that server gzip response and client unzip this response. Is that good idea? Any idea welcome.

Comment: Have you ever considered using some cache techniques for servers?

Comment: @israel.zinc: I used to cache for server with redis. My application is a reporting system with data growth continuously. Caching response send for client large data ( application/json via http response)